# How can i call java script function by clicking x Axis label on Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

i will be thankful to you all if you can tell me how to call java script function clicking by xAxis label on Highchart.
belowe here there's my code.
thanks in advance.

```
var options = {
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'bar',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2)',
    width: 1500,
    height: 800,
    ...
  },
  title: {
    ....
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
},

xAxis: {
 ....
},

yAxis:{
  ...
  },

labels: {
  style: {
      color: 'black',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  }      
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
}, 

tooltip: {
....
},    

series: [] 

};
```

Here how i call my

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  });
```

PS: I found this way to call function by clicking on labels but it doesn't work in my case

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'bar',        
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['chr1','chr2','chr3','chr4'],

        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">'+
                    this.value +'</a>';

            }
        }        
},                       
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5]
        }]
    },function(chart){

        $.each(chart.xAxis[0].ticks,function(i,tick){
            tick.label.on('click',function(){
               alert(tick.pos);
            });
        });

    });
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aPg8H/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is line where you create labels:

```
return '<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">'+
                this.value +'</a>';
```

So you can simply change to this:

```
return '<a href="#" onclick="myFun()">'+
                this.value +'</a>';
```

And should work.

Comment: thank you but it didn't work, anyway i resolved my problem :)

Comment: Interesting, for me it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/aPg8H/6/ - have you set useHTML flag to true?